# Slash run not progressing after importing e.g. pandas

Tags: python, slash

I have an issue with the Slash test framework. It is not progressing as soon as I add some modules, e.g. pandas. Taking this minimal example of a base test.

```
def test_base():
    assert True
```

`slash run base_test.py -vvvv` runs perfectly fine. As soon as I add e.g. pandas slash

```
import pandas as pd

def test_base():
    assert True
```

does not start running the tests, but keeps running indefinitely. The only output I see is

```
 [2023-01-20 09:45:04] Creating new package for base_test.py
 [2023-01-20 09:45:04] After split: D:\testing, base_test
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the test from a shell with administrator rights worked